# VBA web scraper to access search results from JavaScript form

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am working on a web scraper in VBA.

I have a website with a JavaScript form and I don't know how to access a table from the search results of that JavaScript form.

I know how to navigate and pull out the required info from a normal HTML site. I already put in my searching keywords and click the "search" button all through VBA.

After my search (e.g. "SN857X00PE") the search results are displayed in a table:

```
SN857X00PE/01   StudioLine  9702 - 9709
SN857X00PE/38   StudioLine  9711 - 9801
SN857X00PE/42   StudioLine  9802 - 9804
SN857X00PE/46   StudioLine  9805 - 9806
```

I'm looking to access all the left serial numbers (e.g. `SN857X00PE/01`, `SN857X00PE/38` etc.).

When I go into the Firefox debugger I see many `.js` files and an `index.xhtml`.
I can find everything I need in the `index.xhtml` file (code included below with example search `SN857X00PE`) but when I access the HTML through `IE.Document.getElementById("body").InnerHtml` it doesn't show me the content of the `index.xhtml` file but instead the content of the `TP4.js` file (code below).

As you can see below, the `TP4.js` file doesn't include any useful info about the search results or any way to access them.

Is there a way to access the search result table of the JavaScript form? If I am able to put keywords in it and make the search result inside VBA it should be possible the access the results too. I'd like `IE.Documents` to point to the content of the `index.xhtml` file instead of the default `TP4.js` file if that's possible.

When I go to the Firefox inspector to see the HTML the javascript website is producing in the end it looks so easy to access my information. Is there a way to get direct access to the nice and clean "endresult-html" after the browser finishes compiling all the JavaScript?

The website is tradeplace(DOT)com but the Javascript form is hidden behind a login.

Here an overview on how the site looks like when it displays the search results. On the right I am showing the table with the search results inside the index.xhtml that I am trying to access but I don't know how to reach it, since I only have access to the contents of the tp4.js file.

[image]

Due to max character limit, I couldn't include the whole HTML code, here are some parts I think could be important/relevant, so you can get a general idea how the site looks:

index.xhtml:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head id="head">
  <title>Tradeplace Marketplace</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

  <link href="/tp4-web/css/jquery.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/tp4-web/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/tp4-web/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/tp4-web/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/tp4-web/javax.faces.resource/components.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/tp4-web/javax.faces.resource/components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/tp4-web/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/tp4-web/javax.faces.resource/primefaces-extensions.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces-extensions&amp;v=6.0.0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.PrimeFaces) {
      PrimeFaces.settings.locale = 'en_US';
    }
  </script>
  <link href="/tp4-web/css/tp4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/tp4-web/js/tp4.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="body">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      TP4.initPageLayout();
      TP4.enableSubmenus();
    });

    $(window).unload(function() {
      TP4.hideLoadingScreen();
    });
  </script>

  <div id="page">
    <div id="header">

      <div id="logoline" class="clearfix">
        <img id="mainLogo" src="/tp4-web/images/sparetable/logo-tradeplace.png" alt="tradeplace" />
        <img id="sparesLogo" src="/tp4-web/images/sparetable/spares.png" alt="spares" />
        <table id="oemLogo">
          <tr>
            <td valign="middle"><img id="logoLine:brandImage" src="/tp4-web/pages/streamImage.xhtml?type=1&amp;identifier=100001&amp;pfdrid_c=true" alt="" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>


      ------------------------------------------------------------------------- ... SKIPPING SOME CODE UP TO THE RELEVANT CODE PART -------------------------------------------------------------------------



      <tr class="data alt">
        <td>
          <a href="/tp4-web/pages/secure/product/productSearchDetail.xhtml?productNumber=SN857X00PE%2F01&amp;formattedProductNumber=SN857X00PE%2F01&amp;windowId=909" onclick="TP4.showLoadingScreen(this)">
       SN857X00PE/01
      </a>
        </td>

        <td>
          StudioLine
        </td>

        <td>9702 - 9709
        </td>

        <td valign="middle" class="nowrap">
          <span>
       <a href="/tp4-web/pages/secure/product/productSearchDetail.xhtml?productNumber=SN857X00PE%2F01&amp;formattedProductNumber=SN857X00PE%2F01&amp;windowId=909" onclick="TP4.showLoadingScreen(this)">
        <img alt="Dokumente" title="Dokumente" src="/tp4-web/images/icons/docs.gif" /></a>
      </span>
          <span>
        <a href="/tp4-web/pages/secure/product/part/productPartList.xhtml?productNumber=SN857X00PE%2F01&amp;formattedProductNumber=SN857X00PE%2F01&amp;windowId=909" onclick="TP4.showLoadingScreen(this)">
         <img alt="Ersatzteilliste" title="Ersatzteilliste" src="/tp4-web/images/icons/spare.gif" /></a>
       </span>
          <span>
        <a href="/tp4-web/pages/secure/product/explodedView.xhtml?productNumber=SN857X00PE%2F01&amp;formattedProductNumber=SN857X00PE%2F01&amp;typeId1=A02&amp;typeId2=A02E32&amp;typeId3=A02E32V&amp;windowId=909" onclick="TP4.showLoadingScreen(this)">
         <img alt="Explosionszeichnung" title="Explosionszeichnung" src="/tp4-web/images/icons/explos.gif" /></a>
       </span>
          <span>
        <a href="/tp4-web/pages/secure/accessory/accessoryForProduct.xhtml?commercialItemNumber=SN857X00PE%2F01&amp;commercialItemNumberFormatted=SN857X00PE%2F01&amp;windowId=909" onclick="TP4.showLoadingScreen(this)">
         <img alt="Zubehör" title="Zubehör" src="/tp4-web/images/icons/commercial.gif" /></a>
       </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      -------------------------------------------------------------- SKIPPING CODE AGAIN TO THE END -------------------------------------------------------------
    </div>
    <div id="ajaxStatus"></div>
    <script id="ajaxStatus_s" type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        PrimeFaces.cw("AjaxStatus", "ajaxStatusWidget", {
          id: "ajaxStatus",
          start: function() {
            TP4.showLoadingScreen();
          },
          success: function() {
            TP4.hideLoadingScreen();
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
    <div id="loadingDialog" class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-hidden-container">
      <div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
        <table id="loadingScreen">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p><b>Bitte warten - Datenbeschaffung...</b></p>
            </td>
            <td><img src="/tp4-web/images/ajax-loading.gif" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script id="loadingDialog_s" type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        PrimeFaces.cw("Dialog", "loadingDialogWidget", {
          id: "loadingDialog",
          resizable: false,
          modal: true
        });
      });
    </script>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function() {
      (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o),
      m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
  })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-55961901-1', 'auto');


  ga('set', '&uid', '27d62c9d4ec32f32a829bed7142036c05d9516ac93c8935d18acf1fdc3d59145');


  ga('send', 'pageview', {
    'title': 'ProductSearchResult'
  });
</script>

</html>
```

TP4.js

```html
PrimeFaces.widget.ExtImageAreaSelect && (PrimeFaces.widget.ExtImageAreaSelect.prototype.cancelSelection = function () {
  this.instance && this.instance.cancelSelection()
});
TP4 = {
  Constants: {
    PAGE_ELEMENT_SELECTOR: '#page',
    HEADER_ELEMENT_SELECTOR: '#header',
    FOOTER_ELEMENT_SELECTOR: '#footer',
    BASKET_RELOAD_LINK_ID: '#reloadBasketLink',
    BASKET_POPUP_WIDTH: '460',
    BASKET_POPUP_HEIGHT: '400',
    SPECIAL_NOTICE_PART_POPUP_WIDTH: '380',
    SPECIAL_NOTICE_PART_POPUP_HEIGHT: '365',
    SPECIAL_NOTICE_DOCUMENT_LIST_POPUP_WIDTH: '600',
    SPECIAL_NOTICE_DOCUMENT_LIST_POPUP_HEIGHT: '400',
    SPECIAL_NOTICE_DOCUMENT_POPUP_WIDTH: '500',
    SPECIAL_NOTICE_DOCUMENT_POPUP_HEIGHT: '200',
    CUSTOMER_INFO_POPUP_WIDTH: '480',
    CUSTOMER_INFO_POPUP_HEIGHT: '405',
    SMALL_POPUP_WIDTH: '360',
    SMALL_POPUP_HEIGHT: '330',
    MEDIUM_POPUP_WIDTH: '800',
    MEDIUM_POPUP_HEIGHT: '600',
    NON_MODAL_DIALOG_Z_INDEX: 500
  },
  Context: {
    currentDialogZIndex: 0
  },
  showLoadingScreen: function (a) {
    a ? !a.href || a.href && '#' == a.href ? TP4.showLoadingScreenAfterTimeout()  : a.href && PF('loadingDialogWidget').show()  : PF('loadingDialogWidget').show()
  },
  showLoadingScreenAfterTimeout: function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      PF('loadingDialogWidget').show()
    }, 100)
  },
  hideLoadingScreen: function () {
    PF('loadingDialogWidget').hide()
  },
  initPageLayout: function () {
    $(TP4.Constants.PAGE_ELEMENT_SELECTOR).css({
      'padding-top': $(TP4.Constants.HEADER_ELEMENT_SELECTOR).height(),
      'padding-bottom': $(TP4.Constants.FOOTER_ELEMENT_SELECTOR).height()
    })
  },
  adjustElementHeightToAvailableHeight: function (a, b) {
    var c = $(a),
    d = $(TP4.Constants.HEADER_ELEMENT_SELECTOR),
    g = $(TP4.Constants.FOOTER_ELEMENT_SELECTOR),
    e = $(window).height();
    0 < d.length && (e -= d.height());
    0 < g.length && (e -= g.height());
    null != b && (e -= b);
    c.height(e)
  },
  setElementCssHeightToContentHeight: function (a) {
    a = $(a);
    var b = a.height();
    a.css('height', b + 'px')
  },
  setDefaultCommand: function (a, b) {
    a.keydown(function (a) {
      var d = $.ui.keyCode;
      if (a.which ==
      d.ENTER || a.which == d.NUMPAD_ENTER) b.click(),
      a.preventDefault()
    })
  },
  scrollTo: function (a) {
    window.location.hash = '#' + a
  },
  scrollToTop: function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 0)
  },
  scrollToBottom: function (a) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(document).height()
    }, a)
  },
  adjustMarginForTwoColumnLayout: function (a, b) {
    $(b).css({
      'margin-left': $(a).width()
    })
  },
  restoreInputFieldValueFromHtml: function (a) {
    a.each(function (b) {
      $(this).val(a[b].defaultValue)
    })
  },
  disableLoadingScreenModality: function () {
    PF('loadingDialogWidget').cfg.modal = !1
  },
  enableLoadingScreenModality: function () {
    PF('loadingDialogWidget').cfg.modal = !0
  },
  moveDialogBehindModalContainer: function (a) {
    TP4.Context.currentDialogZIndex = a.jq.css('z-index');
    a.jq.css('z-index', TP4.Constants.NON_MODAL_DIALOG_Z_INDEX)
  },
  moveDialogBeforeModalContainer: function (a) {
    a.jq.css('z-index', TP4.Context.currentDialogZIndex)
  },
  synchronizeDialogModality: function (a) {
    TP4.disableLoadingScreenModality();
    TP4.moveDialogBehindModalContainer(a)
  },
  resetDialogModalityToDefault: function (a) {
    TP4.enableLoadingScreenModality();
    TP4.moveDialogBeforeModalContainer(a)
  },
  activateMaxLengthHandlingOnTextareas: function () {
    $('textarea[maxlength]').keyup(function () {
      var a = parseInt($(this).attr('maxlength'));
      $(this).val().length > a && $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, $(this).attr('maxlength')))
    })
  },
  resizeTo: function (a, b, c) {
    var d = - 1 < navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome');
    null != a && (d ? setTimeout(function () {
      a.resizeTo(b, c)
    }, 4)  : a.resizeTo(b, c))
  },
  enableSubmenus: function () {
    $('li').hover(function () {
      var a = $(this);
      a.closest('ul').children('li.hover').removeClass('hover');
      a.addClass('hover');
      a.attr('isHovered', !0)
    }, function () {
      var a = $(this);
      a.removeAttr('isHovered');
      setTimeout(function () {
        a.attr('isHovered') || a.removeClass('hover')
      }, 350)
    })
  },
  redirect: function (a) {
    window.location.href = a
  },
  overwriteIfZero: function (a) {
    0 < a.value.length && '0' == a.value.substring(0, 1) && (a.value = a.value.substring(1), TP4.overwriteIfZero(a))
  },
  Part: {
    showChildList: function (a) {
      $('#childList' + a).show();
      $('#showChildList' + a).hide();
      $('#hideChildList' + a).show()
    },
    hideChildList: function (a) {
      $('#childList' +
      a).hide();
      $('#showChildList' + a).show();
      $('#hideChildList' + a).hide()
    },
    setAllDefaultCommands: function () {
      TP4.setDefaultCommand($('#inputTextDescription'), $('#commandLinkDescription'));
      TP4.setDefaultCommand($('#inputTextPartNumber'), $('#commandLinkPartNumber'));
      TP4.setDefaultCommand($('#inputTextPicPos'), $('#commandLinkPicPos'))
    }
  },
  Basket: {
    openAddToBasketPopUp: function (a) {
      TP4.PopUp.openPopUpWithSize(a.href, a.target, TP4.Constants.BASKET_POPUP_WIDTH, TP4.Constants.BASKET_POPUP_HEIGHT, 0, 0);
      return !1
    },
    initializeDatePicker: function (a) {
      a = $('#requestDeliveryDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: !0,
        changeYear: !0,
        yearRange: '-90:+0',
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImageOnly: !0,
        buttonImage: a + '/images/calendar.gif',
        minDate: 0
      });
      a.attr('readonly', !0);
      a.datepicker('option', 'showAnim', 'show')
    },
    setAllDefaultCommands: function () {
      TP4.setDefaultCommand($('#basketOverviewItemListWrapper input'), $('#updateBasket'))
    }
  },
  SpecialNotices: {
    openSpecialNoticePartPopUp: function (a) {
      TP4.PopUp.openPopUpWithSize(a.href, a.target, TP4.Constants.SPECIAL_NOTICE_PART_POPUP_WIDTH, TP4.Constants.SPECIAL_NOTICE_PART_POPUP_HEIGHT, 0, 0);
      return !1
    },
    openSpecialNoticeDocumentListPopUp: function (a) {
      TP4.PopUp.openPopUpWithSize(a.href, a.target, TP4.Constants.SPECIAL_NOTICE_DOCUMENT_LIST_POPUP_WIDTH, TP4.Constants.SPECIAL_NOTICE_DOCUMENT_LIST_POPUP_HEIGHT, 0, 0);
      return !1
    },
    openSpecialNoticeDocumentPopUp: function (a) {
      TP4.PopUp.openPopUpWithSize(a.href, a.target, TP4.Constants.SPECIAL_NOTICE_DOCUMENT_POPUP_WIDTH, TP4.Constants.SPECIAL_NOTICE_DOCUMENT_POPUP_HEIGHT, 0, 0);
      return !1
    },
    initializeDocumentView: function (a) {
      if (a) {
        a = $('#specialNoticeHeader');
        var b = 0;
        0 < a.length && (b = a.height());
        $('#specialNoticesPdf').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $.browser.webkit ? setTimeout(function () {
          TP4.adjustElementHeightToAvailableHeight('#specialNoticesDocumentContainer', b)
        }, 100)  : TP4.adjustElementHeightToAvailableHeight('#specialNoticesDocumentContainer', b)
      }
    },
    afterAddToBasket: function (a, b) {
      b && TP4.SpecialNotices.initializeDocumentView(a);
      TP4.SpecialNotices.triggerBasketRefreshInMainWindow();
      scroll(0, 0)
    },
    triggerBasketRefreshInMainWindow: function () {
      TP4.SpecialNotices.triggerBasketRefresh(window.opener)
    },
    triggerBasketRefresh: function (a) {
      var b = a.$(TP4.Constants.BASKET_RELOAD_LINK_ID);
      0 < b.length ? (a.TP4.showLoadingScreen(), a.location.href = b.attr('href'))  : a.opener && TP4.SpecialNotices.triggerBasketRefresh(a.opener)
    }
  },
  PopUp: {
    openSmallPopUpForLink: function (a) {
      TP4.PopUp.openPopUpWithSize(a.href, a.target, TP4.Constants.SMALL_POPUP_WIDTH, TP4.Constants.SMALL_POPUP_HEIGHT, 0, 0);
      return !1
    },

-----------------------------------------------------------------
SKIPPING CODE TO THE END
-------------------------------------------------------------------
  Infoline: {
    openCustomerInfoPopUpForLink: function (a) {
      TP4.PopUp.openPopUpWithSize(a.href, a.target, TP4.Constants.CUSTOMER_INFO_POPUP_WIDTH, TP4.Constants.CUSTOMER_INFO_POPUP_HEIGHT, 0, 0);
      return !1
    },
    triggerInfolineRefreshInMainWindow: function () {
      var a = window.opener.$(TP4.Constants.BASKET_RELOAD_LINK_ID);
      0 < a.length ? (window.opener.location.href = a.attr('href'), window.opener.TP4.showLoadingScreen())  : (window.opener.TP4.showLoadingScreen(), window.opener.location.search = TP4.Infoline.getOpenerUrlWithEmptyWindowId())
    },
    getOpenerUrlWithEmptyWindowId: function () {
      for (var a = {
      }, b = window.opener.location.search.substring(1), c = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, d; d = c.exec(b); ) a[decodeURIComponent(d[1])] = decodeURIComponent(d[2]);
      a.windowId = '';
      return $.param(a)
    }
  },
  History: {
    initializeDatePicker: function (a) {
      var b = $('#dateFrom, #dateTo').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: !0,
        changeYear: !0,
        yearRange: '-90:+0',
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImageOnly: !0,
        buttonImage: a + '/images/calendar.gif',
        onSelect: function (a) {
          var d = 'dateFrom' == this.id ? 'minDate' :
          'maxDate',
          g = $(this).data('datepicker');
          a = $.datepicker.parseDate(g.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, a, g.settings);
          b.not(this).datepicker('option', d, a)
        }
      });
      b.attr('readonly', !0);
      b.datepicker('option', 'showAnim', 'show')
    }
  },
  FAQ: {
    Context: {
      selectedIssueId: - 1,
      selectedQuestionsIssueId: - 1,
      selectedQuestionAnchor: ''
    },
    setSelectedIssueId: function (a) {
      TP4.FAQ.Context.selectedIssueId = a;
      TP4.FAQ.Context.selectedQuestionsIssueId = a
    },
    setSelectedQuestionsIssueId: function (a) {
      TP4.FAQ.Context.selectedQuestionsIssueId = a;
      - 1 === TP4.FAQ.Context.selectedIssueId && (TP4.FAQ.Context.selectedIssueId = a)
    },
    setSelectionQuestionAnchor: function (a) {
      TP4.FAQ.Context.selectedQuestionAnchor = 'question' + a
    },
    areQuestionsAlreadyLoaded: function () {
      if (TP4.FAQ.Context.selectedIssueId === TP4.FAQ.Context.selectedQuestionsIssueId) return TP4.FAQ.scrollToAnchor(),
      !1;
      TP4.FAQ.Context.selectedIssueId = TP4.FAQ.Context.selectedQuestionsIssueId
    },
    scrollToAnchor: function () {
      TP4.scrollTo(TP4.FAQ.Context.selectedQuestionAnchor)
    },
    moveOnClickFromInnerLinkToTreeNodeContainer: function (a, b) {
      $(a).find('.ui-treenode-leaf').each(function () {
        var a = $(this).find(b),
        d = a.attr('onclick');
        $(this).attr('onclick', d);
        a.attr('onclick', null)
      })
    }
  }
};
PrimeFaces.widget.Poll = PrimeFaces.widget.BaseWidget.extend({
  init: function (a) {
    this.cfg = a;
    this.id = this.cfg.id;
    this.active = !1;
    this.cfg.autoStart && this.start()
  },
  refresh: function (a) {
    this.isActive() && this.stop();
    this.init(a)
  },
  start: function () {
    this.timer = setInterval(this.cfg.fn, 1000 * this.cfg.frequency);
    this.active = !0
  },
  stop: function () {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
    this.active = !1
  },
  handleComplete: function (a, b, c) {
    c.stop && this.stop()
  },
  isActive: function () {
    return this.active
  }
});
```

Comment: there are multiple results in one page inside a table. I'm pretty new to VBA and Javascript, but your code looks really interesting, with "showLoadingScreen" can you fetch the search results even though there are not listet in the TP4.js?

Right now I see the serial numbers only in the index.xhtml. When you write "showLoadingScreen"  are you accessing the code that is displayed in the index.xhtml?

Comment: here are 2 txt files with 
the complete code of the index.xhtml and tp4.js  (In the next minutes I'll also included txts for all the other js files though I don't think they are relevant) https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pguvw7va1d7xphk/AADlIfO6xvGyX9Rn-oRh0G8wa?dl=0

Comment: there is no ID for the results table, this is it: <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="bordered">

the only results table that I can find is in de index.xhtml . Right now the IE.Document. is pointing to the TP4.js only, but if I can get from the TP4.js to the index.xhtml then I can navigate to the result without problems. My only problem is how to get to the part at all where the table and all the info is.

I let excel show me the complet body of the current IE.Document with IE.Document.getELementsbyID("body") and it showed me 100% the sourcecode of the TP4.js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS selector:**

So using the HTML supplied I can use a CSS selector as follows:

```
#productList td > a
```

This selects elements based on their styling. `"#"` stands for class. The `td > a` means, select all `a` elements where the parent is a `td` element. So select those inside of an element with class `productList`.

I apply the selector using the `querySelectorAll` method of `document` which returns a `nodeList` of matching elements, the length of which I then traverse.

I am reading your HTML in from a file but you could use:

```
ie.document.querySelectorAll("#productList td > a")
```

---

CSS query:

[image: CSS query]

---

**Output to immediate window:**

[image: Output]

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub HTMLQuery()
    Dim oXHTTP As Object, HTML As New HTMLDocument, aNodeList As Object, i As Long
    Set oXHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With oXHTTP
        .Open "GET", "C:\Users\User\Desktop\index.html", False
        .send
        HTML.body.innerHTML = oXHTTP.responseText
        Set aNodeList = HTML.querySelectorAll("#productList td > a")

        For i = 0 To aNodeList.Length - 1
            Debug.Print aNodeList.item(i).innerText
        Next i
   End With
End Sub
```

---

**For your code:**

```
Dim aNodeList As Object
Set aNodeList = IE.document.querySelectorAll("#productList td > a")

For i = 0 To aNodeList.Length - 1
    Debug.Print aNodeList.item(i).innerText
Next i
```

---

Looping with a timer for page to load:

```
While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
Dim t As Date
t = Timer

Do
    DoEvents
    On Error Resume Next
    Set aNodeList = IE.document.querySelectorAll("#productList td > a")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Timer - t = 3 Then Exit Do        '<==To avoid infinite loop. Adjust 3 seconds as required
Loop While aNodeList Is Nothing

If Not aNodeList Is Nothing Then
    For i = 0 To aNodeList.Length - 1
        Debug.Print aNodeList.item(i).innerText
    Next i
End If
```

---

**References:**

You need to go VBE > Tools > References and add a reference to HTML Object Library if using an HTMLDocument variable as I have. You don't need this is accessing direct from `IE.document`.

Comment: do I understand this solution correctly? The "HTML As New HTMLDocument" is where I would assign my "IE.Document" that I get from my VBA scraper, right? - edit: I think you answered that in your edit. Thanks I'll go try it out and report on the results!

Comment: See edit regarding for your code. Provided the page has fully loaded you can just use those 5 lines.

Comment: I just tried it out today and your solution worked flawlessly!